# NOT BETWEEN gives error when work with amount range. when no range of amount matched

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to get a row that has an amount ranges between 2 data columns, and if no range matched then Commission row with null value fetched.

| PackageID | FromAmount | ToAmount | Commission | TypeID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 101 | 500 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 501 | 1000 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | 6 | 1 |

Query -

```
DECLARE @Amount INT = 1010

SELECT fromamount,
       toamount,
       commission,
       typeid
FROM   package
WHERE  ( ( @Amount BETWEEN fromamount AND toamount )
          OR ( @Amount NOT BETWEEN fromamount AND toamount )
             AND ( fromamount IS NULL
                   AND toamount IS NULL ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this as:

```sql
SELECT FromAmount, ToAmount, Commission, TypeID
FROM Package
WHERE @Amount BETWEEN FromAmount AND ToAmount OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Package
                  WHERE @Amount BETWEEN FromAmount AND ToAmount) AND
      FromAmount IS NULL AND ToAmount IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `(@Amount NOT BETWEEN FromAmount AND ToAmount)` after the `OR`:

```
DECLARE @Amount INT = 1010

SELECT FromAmount, ToAmount, Commission, TypeID
FROM Package 
WHERE ((@Amount BETWEEN FromAmount AND ToAmount)
OR (FromAmount IS NULL AND ToAmount IS NULL))
```

Comment: This would return _two_ rows for an amount which matches a range: one row for the matched range, and also the default NULL, NULL row.